# How can I wrap PHP code by HTML?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true);
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_name", true);
?>
```

I tried:

```
echo '<span>get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true);</span>';
```

It's not worked.

Comment: `echo '<span>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true).'</span>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

```
echo '<span>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true).'</span>';
```

You had 2 errors,

1. Single quote will treat everything as text, so your function was treat as rext
2. You had a semicolon after your function

**OPTION 2**

```
<span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true);?></span>
```

**REFERENCE**

AS @paul-crovella recommended you, read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo '<span>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true).'</span>';
```

OR

```
<span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true); ?></span>
```